# Rails Radio Buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm looking to submit a form with radio button selections using the rails form helper. The code works fine when I run it locally, however I get an "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error when deployed with Heroku. For some reason when I delete either radio button, it works fine with Heroku but obviously I need the two.

```
 <label class="radio-inline">
    <%= f.radio_button :by_yourself, 'true', :checked => true %>
    I'm by myself
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <%= f.radio_button :by_yourself, 'false' %>
    Others are around
  </label>
```

I've also tried it using the label method within rails, but get the same error.

```
    <div class="radio-inline">
      <%= f.radio_button(:by_yourself, true) %>
      <%= f.label(:by_yourself_true, "No, I'm by myself") %>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">
        <%= f.radio_button(:by_yourself, false) %>
        <%= f.label(:by_yourself_false, "Yes there are.") %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at your production.log to see what error you get?

Comment: Check your log. `heroku logs`.

Comment: The log shows the following error:            ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `by_yourself'

Comment: by_yourself_true should be attribute of your model. is it added in your db table?

Comment: @raysrashmi by_yourself is an attribute of the model. why would you need by_yourself_true?

Comment: @Galsh `f.label(:by_yourself_true` is what @raysrashmi is referring to I think - from your 2nd block of code (the label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points for you:

**-> What is your model & controller like?**

Your error means that the variable you're using for `form_for` does not have the `by_yourself` element attached

This could be down to a lot of potential issues, but the main is that you've done something  in your model or controller to cause the problem. It would be good for you to show us

**-> Remove your labels (for now)**

For now, get rid of the labels because I think they may provide some syntax errors, as well as making the radio buttons have this syntax:

```
<%= f.radio_button :by_yourself, true %>
<%= f.radio_button :by_yourself, false %>

-> Show us your entire form
```

This would help alot

Comment: Thanks Rich, you and @raysrashmi were correct in saying by_yourself didn't exist in the production database. Running the command "heroku run rake db:reset" solved the problem. (This was fine for me as there was no live data yet)